# How can I run .exe file on ubuntu 12.04 machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, java-ee-7

In my organization C developers developed one Application and given to us as a `.exe` format.

If any end-user send any `Http` request.This `.exe` will be run, for this I wrote the `Java` code(`ProcessBuilder()`) and deployed in `Application Server(Apache Tomcat)`.It's working fine.These everything was done in my local system(Windows 7).

But we are using `Ubuntu 12.04` as a server.Here that `.exe` file is not working.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install wine software if you want to run a .exe file in ubuntu .
installing the wine software in ubuntu is a simple two step process.
Type the command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Once the wine is installed, you can open any .exe file using wine .
Say this , i have a file game.exe , right click - open with - wine .

Comment: Use: `sudo apt-get install wine1.6` as 1.5 is not supported now.

Comment: Yes, wine 1.5 was in 2013 , now you have new updates of wine as 1.7 and 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install wine software if you want to run a .exe file in ubuntu . installing the wine software in ubuntu is a simple two step process. Type the command in the terminal

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine1.5  (1.5 changes with what ever number the latest edition is)

Even better go to Ubuntu software center and install thru GUI based process

Once the wine is installed, you can open any .exe file using wine . Say this , i have a file pumpai.exe , right click - open with - wine .
And Enjoy...Its Open Source..........

Pramod Pai

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't execute a windows executable on Linux (but maybe try with [wine](http://www.winehq.org/)).

You should ask the source code of that C application inside your organization, and port it and compile it (with `gcc -Wall -g` at first) on your Linux server.

I suggest you to install Linux on your local machine (or laptop) to learn it first.

Comment: we already installed `Ubuntu 12.04` and installed `Wine`.It's not working.I think we need to communicate with `C` developers.